# How do I include Unit Test .dll's in drop from TFS Build to include in TFS Release Management?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, ms-release-management

As a part of our continuous deployment pipeline, I've built in a large number of tests in different variety (Unit Tests, Coded UI Tests, etc.). As a part of this, I have a number of integration tests that use the Unit Testing Framework to do things like testing of different database operations. I got these working by manually copying the LocalDb instance and running them as a part of the build.

I'd actually like to get these to run in our Dev environment instead of on the build server and plan to use TestSettings to determine which should run where. That being said, I can't seem to find a way to get TFS Build to include the testing .dll's in its drop. My thinking is that we'll want to copy these as a build artifact. I can access the files fine if not packaging the build in a zip (for RM), but this step seems to throw things off.

I have tried a variety of different configurations of "Copy Publish Artifact" steps (a few examples below w/ different Copy Roots and Contents), but the step never seems to find any files to copy.

[Copy Publish Artifact Ex. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITxXk.png)

[Copy Publish Artifact Ex. 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkyBt.png)

Any help on how to get these testing .dlls included in the drop would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to check where the integration dlls are located in the build folder [image]